# How to integrate Spring Integration and WebPages? JSP , Angular JS?

Tags: spring-integration

What I am looking for is as follows:
I have creates a folder which works as input channel and a folder which works s an output channel. So any files(messages) in the input folder gets passed to the output channel after going through filters.

Now I need to create a UI webpage where maybe I can Stop a particular message from going ahead. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Did you tried using a filter?

Comment: yes, but I want a button on a webpage to start or stop that filter. How can that be achieved?

Comment: Well a filter is also just a bean. Autowire it to your Controller ans manipulate its state, e.g. change the expression of the filter.

Comment: No What I need is some tutorial on how to connect Spring MVC and Spring Integration together.. Is something like that possible?

Comment: Alex, for sure this is possible. Well I don't know exactly what you are asking for. I suggest you check the different Implementations beyond `AbstractMessageSplitter`, e.g. `ExpressionEvaluatingSplitter` if you use SpeL or `MethodInvokingSplitter`if you'd hardwired a bean's method. Besides that everything is just simple Spring logic.